# Custom cursor failing on <img> tag

Tags: html, css, cursor

I tried several ways but the cursor can't be changed on `<img>` elements. I thought it's because the `<img>` tags are in `<pre>` tag, but even using !important cannot change the cursor. How do i change the cursor?

Here's my page:http://post.dachaocai.com/24
And I also created a jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/URBew/

Comment: `cursor: pointer;` is working fine for me on css for the images on your site, maybe the problem is with the custom cursor itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to add a fallback keyword value. http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/URBew/1/

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. I even didn't know there's a 'fallback keyword' before.

Answer (score 2):

```
pre img{cursor:url("http://img.t.sinajs.cn/t4/style/images/common/small.cur"), default;}
```

You must add generic cursor at the end, and all will work fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/URBew/4/